# Adding an arrow or x to custom Android Button using XML

Tags: android, xml, button

I'm working on creating the elements for my Android app's user interface.  Right now, I've got a few different custom button styles that I've created in XML Selector files.  Is there a way I can overlay or add simple shapes (like an arrow or an x) to my custom buttons?  Here's a couple photo examples to clarify what I"m looking for.

[Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ibJr.png) 
or 
[X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWUeH.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set CompoundDrawable of button to do that:

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
```